# Apply fuzzy ratio to two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, fuzzywuzzy

I have two dataframes where **I want to fuzzy string compare & apply my function to two dataframes**:

```
sample1 = pd.DataFrame(data1.sample(n=200, random_state=42))
sample2 = pd.DataFrame(data2.sample(n=200, random_state=13))

def get_ratio(row):
    sample1 = row['address']
    sample2 = row['address']
    return fuzz.token_set_ratio(sample1, sample2)
match = data[data.apply(get_ratio, axis=1) >= 78] #I want to apply get_ratio to both sample1 and sample2
no_matched = data[data.apply(get_ratio, axis=1) <= 77] #I want to apply get_ratio to both sample1 and sample2
```

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

Comment: How the comparison should apply: `1 -> 1` or `1 -> N`? Do you want a result for the product of combination of (sample1, sample2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the permutations of your addresses. Then use that to compare the matching ones. You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978444/how-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-to-match-based-on-a-few-columns/68979157#68979157).

For your case first you need to create permutations:

```
combs = list(itertools.product(data1["address"], data2["address"]))
combs = pd.DataFrame(combs)
```

Then use the proper method for matching:

```
combs['score'] = combs.apply(lambda x: fuzz.token_set_ratio(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
```

now based on the score you can find the ones that have matched or have not matched.

I advise you do try to group and clean the addresses first (i.e., lowering the case, removing the duplicates) Otherwise it might take a very long time to compute.

Comment: Thank you! Yup thats what I needed. Also thanks for linking the other relevant posting - sometimes I just cant find what I am looking for in SO.

Comment: @a1234 Happy to help! When topics become too specialized, several terms are used for them. It is hard to search for the right answer in such cases :)